# Fetch data from realtime database using orderby

Tags: firebase

I am using the below code which fetches the data of database `users`. I want to ascending order it by `age`.

```
//fetch all data
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('users/');
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Attached screenshot for reference:

[image]

How can I get the minimum age record to be on top?

**Edit :: 1**

1. age is a number in database

I tried order by child with below code but still no expected result.

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('users/');
starCountRef.orderByChild("age").on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

[image]

result is still the same
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should update structure of the users collection so that the age property is a number (not a string). So you'll simply need to use orderBy. Something like this:

```js
const starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild("age");
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

At the moment, the age property is a string so sorting will not behave as expected ("11" would come before "3" or "4")

Comment: Property 'orderBy' does not exist on type 'Reference'. Now my age is a number, i even tried `    var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('users/').orderByChild("age");`  still doesnt work, i edited by question for your reference

Comment: It is still not giving the expected result

Comment: @user2828442 Yes, you're right. I was mixing firestore with realtime-database :)